# java if else syntax

Tags: java, if-statement

Im using the scanner to accept what type of wood will be chosen based on the variable " m , o p". im using the if and else statement to print out the type of wood which was chosen but im getting an error when it comes to else.

```
package furniture_store;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author whitneykenny
 */
public class Furniture_store {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner type_Furniture = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose a type of wood");
    
    System.out.println("Choose P for pine wood " + "Choose M for mahogany " + "O for Oak");
    String woodType = type_Furniture.nextLine();
    String p,o,m ;

    if (woodType.equals("p")) {
      System.out.println("Pine wood was chosen ");
    } else if (woodType.equals("o")) 
       System.out.println("Oak wood was chosen");

    {
    } 

    else (woodType.equals("m")); 

    {
      System.out.println("Mahogony wood was chosen");
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

Comment: *Copy/paste error / typo:* 1) The `else if` has the `{` misplaced. Move the `{` up one line. --- 2) The `else` is missing an `if` and has an extraneous `;` before the `{`. Add the `if` and remove the `;`.

Comment: I have re-formatted your code, inserted empty lines and corrected indentation. This way it may become obvious what the semicolons do that you've inserted. (otherwise, go with the answer that's already given). For future questions: Please give more information than "I'm getting an error" - we prefer the full error message, if only to see immediately that this is a compile-time problem, not a runtime problem. See [ask].

Comment: Aside comment: the prompts request user to enter _upper-case_ letters `P, M, O` while the code expects _lower-case_ in `woodType` `p, m, o`; it's definitely worth to use `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 3):

In an if/else statement the else cannot have any conditions/parameters.

You could do it like this where no matter the input the last option will be Mahognoy:

```
if (woodType.equals("p")) {
    System.out.println("Pine wood was chosen ");
}else if (woodType.equals("o")) {
    System.out.println("Oak wood was chosen");   
}else{
    System.out.println("Mahogony wood was chosen");
}
```

Or like this with an additional `else if`:

```
if (woodType.equals("p")) {
    System.out.println("Pine wood was chosen ");
}else if (woodType.equals("o")) {
    System.out.println("Oak wood was chosen");  
}else if (woodType.equals("m")){
    System.out.println("Mahogony wood was chosen");
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: That code has the exact same error as the question code, so this doesn't answer anything.

Comment: @Andreas Please elaborate? The code should function as desired by the OP.

Comment: Since it doesn't compile, it can't function. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299524/java-if-else-syntax/66299557?noredirect=1#comment117212702_66299524). The code error is a **typo**, that's all.

Comment: Good spotting on the bracers. Fixed

Comment: Not fixed. Try again. Or don't, and just delete the answer, since the problem is a dumb typo with an extraneous `;`. The question/answer is not useful, because anyone else having the same issue won't find it when searching. The question should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to an `if/if else/.../else` cascade is the `switch` statement:

```
switch (woodType.toLowerCase()) {
    case "p":
        System.out.println("Pine wood was chosen ");
        break;
    case "o": 
        System.out.println("Oak wood was chosen");
        break;
    case "m":
        System.out.println("Mahogony wood was chosen");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("\"" + woodType + "\" is not a valid type of wood");
        break; 
}
```

A `switch` can be easier to read than an if-cascade, and faster too---especially when the number of alternatives becomes larger.

Comment: Although `switch` can be a good alternative, this answer doesn't explain what was wrong with the code in the question, because there is no reason to change to `switch` for the question code.